# How i can edit ONE word using Selenium Python without affecting whole text?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

How i can modify only one word using JS in Selenium?

```
words = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'Hello!'", words)
```

The problem is that it overwrite whole text, instead i want to change only the first word.
For example, i have text: "Hi, how are you?", and i want to change only the first word and get "Hello, how are you?"
When i execute the command above, i get only "Hello", since it overwrite whole sentence.
Can somebody help me how to do it? Thank you in advance

Comment: What is ``words``? If it's supposed to be a full sentence, split and rejoin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the word `Hi!` with `Hello!` with the example `<div>` below

```
<div>
    Hi! 0xNinja
</div>
```

Instead of replacing the only word you can set the entire *`innerText`* as follows:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'Hello! 0xNinja'", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div"))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that rest of the text change every time i reload, so i want to leave it as it is.

Comment: Can i somehow select/mark the first word and then replace it?